# Is it possible to get reviewer details from facebook pages using graph api?

Tags: facebook, rating, review

I can fetch review text but can not fetch reviewer info like name,image , how to get those.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I wanted to show them as api response, for a project @WizKid

Comment: That doesn't explain why you need them.

Comment: I implement this problem brother. and solve this issue. actually it was page scope issue.. thanks brother for your active answers. @WizKid